# Using iPhone LCD with Arduino

Tags: iphone, arduino, lcd

Is it possible to use any LCD with Arduino or do I need to stick to some for which the libraries are available?

I'm just starting out with Arduino and know nothing about interfacing LCDs with Arduino. I'm planing to buy an old iPhone LCD as they are cheap and big enough to do something useful with them. Also to use an iPhone LCD do I need to add some extra circuit or will directly plugging the iPhone LCD into Arduino work? I don't care about the touch feature right now.

Comment: Here is a project showing how to interface with an iphone 4 LCD: https://hackaday.io/project/364-mipi-dsi-display-shieldhdmi-adapter

Answer (score 2):

You will have to interface some gLCD's (if not *all* of them) with the libraries available.

I used this gLCD for my first project:
http://www.skpang.co.uk/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=91_99&products_id=655

Datasheet for this particular gLCD screen here:
http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/Monochrome/Corrected-SFE-0016-DataSheet-08884-SerialGraphicLCD-v2.pdf

Alongside the following library (KS0108):
http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/GLCDks0108

It is quite easy to draw and animate on, but the refresh rate isn't great (a good starters platform!).

Hope that helps!

**p.s. The only thing I could find about iPhone LCDs and Arduinos was: http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9188**

Comment: I saw it, but it is too expensive in comparison to LCD which can be bought at other places. Also I wasn't able to find any one in the internet using it with Arduino or compatible microcontroller.

Comment: Really, I found loads: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ks0108+arduino&aq=f

Comment: I ment using Arduino with Iphone LCD.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use any LCD with Arduino or do I need to stick to some for which the libraries are available?

You need to stick with LCDs that support Arduino and have libraries for them.

There are some low end LCDs that could be made to support the Arduino, but it's not trivial to bring up a new LCD interface on a microcontroller, so I suggest you stick with existing LCDs meant to be used with the Arduino.

> Also to use an iPhone LCD do I need to add some extra circuit or will directly plugging the iPhone LCD into Arduino work? I don't care about the touch feature right now.

The iPhone LCDs require significantly more speed and memory than the Arduino can provide.  In order to drive them you'd essentially need a complete display controller between the Arduino and the LCD.

Due to the Arduino's limited performance and memory, you should plan on using Arduino specific LCD displays.